# Unable to get interrupt handlers to work in C

Tags: c, vector, dos, interrupt, turbo-c

I am currently having trouble getting interrupt handlers to work in C. The idea with my code is to set a vector to IRQ 0, which is the PIT, and from what I can find is interrupt 8 (0x08), after setting the PIT to operate on about 40hz (which from what I can find this is by setting a value of 29829, or 0x7485.

The final intended result of the program is to count to a second, print something to screen, and then repeat that 20 times, at which point it uninstalls itself.

This program was compiled using Borland's Turbo C on an Am486-DX4-100 running at 120mhz with IBM's PC-DOS 2000. The board is the Socket 3 EXP-4045 by DataExpert, but I have the same results on DOSBox.

Here is the code:

```
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
void interrupt clocktick(){
    if(a == 40){
        if(b == 20){
            setvect(8, NULL);
        }else b++;
    }else a++;
}
int main(void){
    /* set PIT mode*/
    outp(0x34, 0x43);
    outp(0x85,0x40); /* send low byte*/
    outp(0x74,0x40); /* send high byte*/
    setvect(0x08, clocktick);
    while(1==1){
        printf("a%i, b%i", a, b);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine, and when ran, the while look does show that A has been incremented once, but doesn't fire again. Obviously something is generating an interrupt, and it may even be the PIT, but it's not doing it more than once.

I am trying to follow the 1987 user's manual for Turbo C, which tries to describe the method for installing interrupt vectors, but I've obviously done something wrong.

I also need to say I am sorry for not knowing this stuff. I don't mean to waste people's time, but I am in genuine need of a helping hand. My examples were vauge, and after some comments I do see there is stuff I could have done to try to figure out what was going on.

Comment: ^^ waht @EOF says.  Even with a toy 'single user' OS like IBM pseudo-DOS, it's quite possible that printf() etc. requries interrupts enabled and so will not run from an interrupt-handler.   You need a debugger, really, to do stuff like this, and I've no idea what youi might use in that environment:(

Comment: What does 'setvect' do?  Does it unmask the interrupt as well as setting the vector?  Where is the EOI sent to the PIC?

Comment: Anyways, I changed some stuff. I apologize for not being descriptive enough. It's hard to be descriptive when I am at a fair loss. From what I can tell, the interrupt is firing at least once, but it won't do it more than once. It might be my while loop clogging it up, but an interrupt should fire anywhere

Comment: The interrupt comntroller requires an EOI byte, (End Of Interrupt) sent to it.  Where does that happen?

Comment: From what I can tell, the Turbo C manual states that setvect send the EOI signal to the PIC.

Comment: I checked the date of this post multiple times to ensure it didn't come from 1990. On the other hand, I find it fantastic that, in 2018, there's at least someone that tries to understand how interrupt vectors work. This gives me hope for the future :) Keep it up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to tell the PIC that you've finished handling the interrupt, otherwise it won't signal it again. Typically this is done by sending an EOI (0x20) to the PIC base port (0x20), so it would essentially be something like `outportb(0x20, 0x20);`, preferably near the end of your handler.

There's some information about the PIC at e.g. https://wiki.osdev.org/8259_PIC

Comment: The Turbo C manual did state that the setvect command does that for me, but this would explain a lot. I'm currently trying the example in the TC manual to make sure that it works, but I will try this immediately after. Thank you

Comment: I need to thank you a lot for this. The TC manual threw me off a bit by not doing this at all. I'm not even sure if the example in there would work, but all I know is that this definitely does.

Comment: I've never known setvect to do that for you, and the fact that you have to give it 0x8 instead of 0x0 is evidence that it doesn't handle the PIC at all. Can you maybe show what it actually says, just to be sure?

Comment: http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_c/Turbo_C_Users_Guide_1987.pdf
Page 238

Comment: It is possible I completely misunderstood what they were talking about. I often jump from resource to resource to give me a better understanding of what exactly is going on.

Comment: setvect() is only called when b == 20, so even if it does send an EOI, (which I doubt, because that's not the place to do it), it would not help you.   The EOI MUST be sent on every interrupt, as @Ove describes.

Comment: If setvect() does only what it suggests by its name, loading the vector with NULL will just cause the next interrupt to run from address 0, which I'm guessing is not what you want.  If you want to stop the interrupt, you have to mask it off or disable its source.

Comment: Yeah, that manual says nothing about EOIs, it shows an interrupt routine that's called from user code, not from the PIC.

Comment: That would make more sense. Thank you.

Comment: Martin James is right, you should get the old address with getvect() first, then when your program is done, set the interrupt vector back to the old address, instead of NULL.