# What is wrong with the C code 'void interrupt (*OldIntrSrvc)();' (circa 1993!)

Tags: c

I am trying to resurrect a C program (from 1993) and am getting a number of errors and warning (using eclipse IDE 2023-09, MinGW 2021-09-05).

In particular, the following code snippet creates an error below:

```
 typedef struct SERIALCOM {
  void  interrupt (*IntrSrvc)(void);
  void  interrupt (*OldIntrSrvc)();
  SRVCFUNC        Subr[4];
  };
```

produces the error:

```
..\src\comms.h:38:20: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
   void  interrupt (*IntrSrvc)(void);
                    ^
```

and

```
..\src\comms.h:39:20: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
   void  interrupt (*OldIntrSrvc)();
                   ^
```

Can anyone shed a light on the error - and the fix??

In the years gone by the (whole) program compiled and ran as required, but it seems the current C compiler must be quite different (though I cannot remember what compiler/linkers were used)

Comment: [Standard C has no interrupt keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353619/can-someone-explain-this-function-pointer-syntax). [There was one in Borland/Turbo C/++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48490893/unable-to-get-interrupt-handlers-to-work-in-c).

Comment: "I cannot remember what compiler/linkers were used" Wasn't it burried in the same sarkophagas the code?

Comment: https://archive.org/details/bcpp31 <- for your software archaeology needs

Comment: Also interrupts are very CPU specific so you need to specify the target.

Comment: This program was intended to run under MS-DOS or WIN95-98?

Comment: If you are trying to convert the program to run on a modern operating system, you are going to have to replace all that low-level interrupt service routine stuff with whatever API the operating system provides.